# Rails - how to code 'may belong to?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app that will contain information on a bunch of people. There are two use cases:

1. An administrator enters and maintains a person's profile
2. The person can decide to sign up, log in, and maintain their own profile

I'm trying to work out the relationship between the profile and the user. Right now, it's that `profile belongs_to :user`, and `user has_one :profile`.

But this breaks, because some profiles have no user yet - they are administrator-maintained. In that case, the `user_id` column in `profiles` is null, the join fails, and the page won't load.++

**How might I set up a "possibly belongs_to" kind of relationship?**

++*(Actually, it comes up blank, with no error displayed, and `development.log` doesn't have any errors either, but I can see that it's not finishing all the queries it does for a profile that does have a user. If anybody knows how I can get a helpful error message instead, that would also be great.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right way to do it. `belongs_to` doesn't prevent `null` values, and this sounds like what you want.

The "page" for a profile that doesn't yet belong to a user might not have as many queries, because there's no need (or way) to query the users table for that profile.

You should check `profile.user` for `nil` and present your views accordingly.

Comment: "may belong to" is `belongs_to` but with robust checks to handle both when the profile's `user` exists, and when it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If a `Profile` really belongs to a `User`, then it shouldn't ever be null (just like it doesn't make sense to consider an `Engine` without the `Car` it's attached to). So you need to delete the `Profile.belongs_to :user` association.

Now you should be able to freely edit `Profiles` and simply attach them to a `User` once they're ready. But you have another problem:

> The person can decide to sign up, log in, and maintain their own profile

How does the system reliably identify which pre-created profile belongs to a particular user that doesn't yet have a profile? That's a design issue you'll have to sort out.

Comment: You're right - "sign up" wasn't the right term. My plan is to have new user accounts created by an administrator (the app will be used in a setting where these people know each other). When the admin creates a new user, he/she will assign a profile to that user.